# How "Subscribe to our newsletter" checkbox works for signup newsletter at checkout pages in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-commerce

Can anybody tell the workflow of "Subscribe to our newsletter" checkbox at checkout page in Drupal commerce.
Currently i need to sign-up a user for newsletter who has this checkbox checked after completing a checkout. But don't know how to make newsletter API call after getting checkbox checked for an order.

Even don't know the work flow of this checkbox.
Please help if anybody have a clear idea about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which of available newsletter module you using? , you can install this module [Commerce simplenews checkout](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_simplenews_checkout) if you decide to use simplenews newsletter.